# Applying filters on child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

**ParentWrapperTable**
 `ID       Name`
 `1       ppp`

**ParentTable**
`ID ParentWrapperID     ChildWrapperID      ExpiryDate`
`1  1                   1                   10/05/2016`
`2  1                   1                   NULL`

**ChildWrapperTable**
`ID Name`
`1  ccc`

**ChildTable**
`ID ChildWrapperID      GrandChildWrapperID ExpiryDate`
`1  1                   1                   11/05/2016`
`2  1                   1                   NULL`

**GrandChildWrapperTable**
`ID Name`
`1  ggg`

**GrandChildTable**
`ID GrandChildWrapperID ExpiryDate`
`1  1                   12/05/2016`
`2  1                   NULL`

The above continuing in multiple levels (i.e. grandgrandchild, etc.). 1-many relationship between the WrapperTable (i.e. ParentWrapperTable) and the normal one (i.e. ParentTable).

I'm using entity framework. I would like to get the Parent record for the name 'ppp' and expirydate is null and all the linked dependencies records where expiry date is null but I would be able to apply the filter only on the parent level. So I'm getting one parent record, 2 child and 2 grandchild records but it should be 1 record for parent, child and grandchild. Could anyone help me to apply the expirydate filter in all the levels (it can be more than 10 levels) in generic way?

```
    var series = ctx.ParentTable.Where(s => s.ExpiryDate == null)


            if (series != null && series.Any())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                {
                    var wrapper = ctx.ParentWrapperTable.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == name);
                    if (wrapper != null)
                    {
                        series = series.Where(c => c.ParentWrapperID == wrapper.ID);

                        if (series.Any())
                            seriesList = series.ToList();
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve your goal with [Table-Per-Hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph):

I have reconfigured your database as shown in these images:

[image: Parent Child Grandchild Table]

[image: Parent Child Grandchild Wrapper]

Using code-first, I created the database and data with the following code:

```
static void CreateAndSeedDatabase()
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            ParentWrapper parentWrapper = new ParentWrapper() { Name = "ppp" };
            ChildWrapper childWrapper = new ChildWrapper() { Name = "ccc" };
            GrandChildWrapper grandChildWrapper = new GrandChildWrapper() { Name = "ggg" };

            ParentTable parentTable1 = new ParentTable { ChildWrapper = childWrapper, Wrapper = parentWrapper, ExpiryDate = "10/5/2015" };
            ParentTable parentTable2 = new ParentTable { ChildWrapper = childWrapper, Wrapper = parentWrapper, ExpiryDate = null };

            ChildTable childTable1 = new ChildTable { Wrapper = childWrapper, ChildWrapper = grandChildWrapper, ExpiryDate = "11/5/2015" };
            ChildTable childTable2 = new ChildTable { Wrapper = childWrapper, ChildWrapper = grandChildWrapper, ExpiryDate = null };

            GrandChildTable grandChildTable1 = new GrandChildTable { Wrapper = grandChildWrapper, ExpiryDate = "12/5/2015" };
            GrandChildTable grandChildTable2 = new GrandChildTable { Wrapper = grandChildWrapper, ExpiryDate = null };

            context.Wrappers.Add(parentWrapper);
            context.Wrappers.Add(childWrapper);
            context.Wrappers.Add(grandChildWrapper);

            context.Tables.Add(parentTable1);
            context.Tables.Add(parentTable2);

            context.Tables.Add(childTable1);
            context.Tables.Add(childTable2);

            context.Tables.Add(grandChildTable1);
            context.Tables.Add(grandChildTable2);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

My context class is defined as:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public DbSet<Wrapper> Wrappers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

My entities are:

```
public abstract class Wrapper {
    public int WrapperId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentWrapper: Wrapper{}
public class ChildWrapper:ParentWrapper{}
public class GrandChildWrapper : ChildWrapper { }

public abstract class Table
{
    public int TableId { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public Wrapper Wrapper { get; set; }
    public Wrapper ChildWrapper { get; set; }
}

public class ParentTable:Table{}

public class ChildTable:Table{}

public class GrandChildTable:Table{}
```

The following code runs your query:

```
    static void QueryDatabase()
    {
        Context context = new Context();
        ParentTable[] result = context.Tables.Include("Wrapper").Include("ChildWrapper").OfType<ParentTable>().Where(t => t.ExpiryDate == null).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bwyn. Unfortunately I wont be able to change the table structure in the current design.